Table center-centered
How do I get the first column as centered as the other ones?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\title{Table}
\author{Armin Weber}
\date{April 2024}

\begin{document}



\maketitle

\section{Introduction}


\newpage

\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|M{2cm}|M{8cm}|M{2cm}|M{2cm}|}

\hline
\rule{0pt}{25pt} {\textbf{Aufgabe}} & \textbf{Erklärung} & \textbf{Punkte} & \textbf{Erreicht} \\ 
\hline
\rule{0pt}{25pt}               1                        &       5             &                 &   \\ 
\hline
\rule{0pt}{25pt}                     2                  &         6           &                 &   \\
\hline
\rule{0pt}{25pt}           3                            &          7          &                 &   \\
\hline  
\rule{0pt}{25pt}               4                        &         8           &                 &   \\
\hline
\rule{0pt}{25pt}                                       &                    &                 &   \\ 
\hline
\rule{0pt}{25pt}                                       &                    &                 &   \\
\hline 
\rule{0pt}{25pt}                                       &                    &                 &   \\
\hline
\rule{0pt}{25pt}                                       &                    &                 &   \\
\hline
\rule{0pt}{25pt}                                       &                    &                 &  
                                       \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}



What are those rules suppose to do? Try changing 0pt to 1pt in the rule of the first row, and you'll see the problem. The rules are only in the first column, that it why it looks different. Probably better to build them into the  M specifier. Remember the optional arg for \rule: \rule[depth]{width}{height} then  you can also make space below and thus control the height of the cells.

Welcome to TeX.SX!

Can you please make a more complete example of the text that's supposed to be in the table? A proper solution needs knowing a bit more.

I would build the struts into the M specifier instead
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand\strutwd{0pt}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\rule{\strutwd}{25pt}\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}<{\rule[-10pt]{\strutwd}{25pt}}   }
\title{Table}
\author{Armin Weber}
\date{April 2024}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}


\newpage

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|M{2cm}|M{8cm}|M{2cm}|M{2cm}|}

\hline
  {\textbf{Aufgabe}}   & \textbf{Erklärung} & \textbf{Punkte} & \textbf{Erreicht} \\ 
\hline
               1       & 5                  &                 &                   \\ 
\hline
                     2 & 6                  &                 &                   \\
\hline
           3           & 7                  &                 &                   \\
\hline  
               4       & 8                  &                 &                   \\
\hline
                       &                    &                 &                   \\ 
\hline
                       &                    &                 &                   \\
\hline 
                       &                    &                 &                   \\
\hline
                       &                    &                 &                   \\
\hline
                       &                    &                 & 
                                                                                  \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}

